# Prevent selection for double click only

Tags: css

In my web application, I have several clickable elements handled by JavaScript. As an example, my table got clickable header text to order the table on client side:

```
<tr>
    <th><a>Name</a></th>
    <th><a>Price</a></th>
    <th><a>Date</a></th>
</tr>
```

It works great, except the header text gets highlighted (selected) if I click twice fast enough. I know there is a cure for that:

```
th a {
    user-select: none;
}
```

It fixes the problem, but what if I don't want to disable the selection entirely? If I select all page contents or just drag selection over these links, I'd like them to be selected and ready to be copied.

Is there any CSS solution for this? I'm surprised there's no `user-select` value to prevent only this kind of selection.

**UPDATE**

I just thought of this:

```
thead a:active {
    user-select: none;
}
```

It seems to work as needed. Are there any potential pitfalls with this idea? Is it commonly used?

Comment: well, if any a tag inside thead is active it will not being clickable. It can be clickable if there are any render lag. Maybe the best option is to preventdefault with js and then make whatever and then let it as default... Or your problem is only a visual thing?

Comment: @JoelBonetR Are you sure you understand the question?

Comment: Nope, so I'm asking if it's only a visual issue (when you doucble click it selects the string) or it can cause an issue on the js?

Comment: There is no issue, clicking always works. It just gives a bad impression when a "button" has its text selected when you click on it.

Comment: ok, and using thead a:active{ user-select: none; } lets you click again after some seconds on the same button or it does not?

Comment: CSS doesn’t affect clicking at all. It just affects text selection.

Comment: Ok so you're done, answer your own question! :) happy to see that you reached what you want by yourself, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for this JS-less approach. I tried preventDefault, it does not work. I tried `window.getSelection().empty()`, it works, but there's a momentary flash of highlighting. I have a headword of longer word, e.g.,: `元末明初`, but if the user double-clicked on middle part of that text, the browser highlights partially only, it only highlights `末明`, not the whole `元末明初`, so it's better not to have a momentary highlighting at all. Your CSS solution, allows the user to still be able to select the text, while preventing partial highlighting of text when double clicking the headword